# Deep Javascript check if undefined without TypeError

Tags: javascript, syntax, undefined, typeerror, isset

I'm tired to write something like

```
if (
  typeof Foo != 'undefined' &&
  typeof Foo.bar != 'undefined' &&
  typeof Foo.bar.baz != 'undefined' &&
  Foo.bar.baz == 'qux'
) {...}
```

In PHP it's a little bit better:

```
if (!empty($foo['bar']['baz']) && $foo['bar']['baz'] == 'qux') {...}
```

Ideally it would be:

```
function u(value) {
    return (typeof value != 'undefined') ? value:null;
}
if (u(Foo.bar.baz) == 'qux') {...}
```

But browser shows "TypeError" when I try to do this. Is there any way to make "u" function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript test for existence of nested object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)

Comment: i have tested your code it is working, in which browser you are getting error? could you also post your Foo

Comment: just run this in your console.. "typeof abc.xyz"
it will throw an error!

Comment: @aamir, there is no error in this code, question was about the complex if statement and how to aviod

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***April 2020 Update***

As of Node.JS version 14, you can now use the following syntax for "optional chaining"

```
if(foo?.bar?.obj?.prop1)
```

If any of the chained properties don't exist, then the value will be typed "undefined".

https://v8.dev/features/optional-chaining

---

***Original reply:***

You don't have to state the undefined explicitly. The check can be something like:

```
if(foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.obj && foo.bar.obj.prop1)
```

Or you can have a try catch block to catch if there is any error:

```
try
{
  if(foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.obj && foo.bar.obj.prop1)
    {}
}
catch(e)
{
 alert(e);
}
```

But yes I can see the problem. I would suggest to try and avoid deep nesting like you have.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem I use [Lodash _.get](https://lodash.com/docs#get).

```
if(_.get(Foo, ['bar','baz'] === 'qux') doThings()
```

If `Foo.bar` or `Foo.bar.baz` are undefined, you will not get a type error, and it's quite a bit easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new optional chaining operator in JavaScript. As of 2020 it is working only in the newest version of the popular browsers. So I recommend using it only with transpilers.

```
if (Foo && Foo?.bar?.baz == 'qux') {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you assume that every steps in your chain is an object and  not 0, "" or boolean false you can write:

```
if (
 Foo  &&
 Foo.bar &&
 Foo.bar.baz &&
 Foo.bar.baz == 'qux'
) {...}
```

But after all its better not to have such deep nested objects